# How to compare json value from unknow key in Python

Tags: python, json

i have a json file but i can't compare value. I want compare two item in the json but i don't know. Let's explain with example

```
{
"Unibet": {
    "Philadelphia 76ers - Atlanta Hawks": {
        "Performance du Joueur (Points + Rebonds + Passes)": {
            "Clint Capela - Moins de 24.5": 1.78,
            "Clint Capela - Plus de 24.5": 1.8,
            "John Collins - Moins de 25.5": 1.84,
            "John Collins - Plus de 25.5": 1.76,
            "Kevin Huerter - Moins de 18.5": 1.84,
            "Kevin Huerter - Plus de 18.5": 1.76,
            "Trae Young - Moins de 44.5": 1.82,
            "Trae Young - Plus de 44.5": 1.78
        },
        "Nombre de rebonds du joueur": {
            "Clint Capela - Moins de 11.5": 1.96,
            "Clint Capela - Plus de 11.5": 1.66,
            "John Collins - Moins de 8.5": 1.86,
            "John Collins - Plus de 8.5": 1.74,
            "Kevin Huerter - Moins de 3.5": 2.1,
            "Kevin Huerter - Plus de 3.5": 1.6,
            "Trae Young - Moins de 3.5": 1.96,
            "Trae Young - Plus de 3.5": 1.66
        },
        "Nombre de passes du joueur": {
            "Clint Capela - Moins de 0.5": 1.88,
            "Clint Capela - Plus de 0.5": 1.72,
            "John Collins - Moins de 0.5": 2.45
        }
    }
},
"Parions Sport": {
    "Philadelphie - Atlanta": {
        "Performance du Joueur - Total Points + Rebonds + Passes - Match": {
            "C.Capela - Plus 24,5": 1.8,
            "C.Capela - Moins 24,5": 1.8,
            "J.Collins - Plus 25,5": 1.8,
            "J.Collins - Moins 25,5": 1.8,
            "K.Huerter - Plus 18,5": 1.8,
            "K.Huerter - Moins 18,5": 1.8,
            "Tr.Young - Plus 44,5": 1.8,
            "Tr.Young - Moins 44,5": 1.8,
            "Se.Curry - Plus 21,5": 1.8,
            "Se.Curry - Moins 21,5": 1.8,
            "J.Embiid - Plus 47,5": 1.8,
            "J.Embiid - Moins 47,5": 1.8,
            "To.Harris - Plus 31,5": 1.8,
            "To.Harris - Moins 31,5": 1.8,
            "F.Korkmaz - Plus 13,5": 1.8,
            "F.Korkmaz - Moins 13,5": 1.8,
            "B.Simmons - Plus 28,5": 1.8,
            "B.Simmons - Moins 28,5": 1.8
        }
    }
}}
```

I want to compare Unibet and Parions Sport, but i want to compare each value and find difference between items. If someone have an issue, thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no automatic way to do that.  The two sites use different formats for their data.  You may have to write a "data cleaner" that convert formats to something comparable.    Like, remove the team name from the Unibet data, change the first name to an initial, etc.  After you have the data in a common format, then you can compare it.